# Cannot loop when using methods in java

Tags: java, methods

Sorry for this guys, but I really am unlucky today.
Please help, my problem a while ago was that I'm having problems while looping, and now it cannot loop at all. It won't let me enter the string to make it loop. 
Name, and year and section also outputs as null. I also tried using try catch but it doesn't seem to be picking up any errors.
Here's the whole program. It just terminates, exactly on:

> enter 1 to continue;

```
import java.util.*;

public class program
{
     public static Scanner rew= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String name, yearandsec;
    public static char sex_code;

    public static int scode;
    public static double seq;
    public static int ccode;
    public static int units;
    public static double fee_per_unit;
    public static double misc;
    public static double gross;
  public static String dec;


    public static String decision;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dec;
        do {
            System.out.println("Input info:");
            String name = stringGetter("Name: ");
            String yearandsec = stringGetter("Year and section: ");

 sex_code=charGetter("Sex code: " + "\n"  + "[M]" + "\n" + "[F]:");
        scode=intGetter("Scholarship code: ");
        ccode=intGetter("Course code: ");
        units=intGetter("Units: ");

        fee_per_unit=doubleGetter("Fee per unit: ");
        misc=doubleGetter("Miscellaneous: ");
        display();
         switches(scode, units, fee_per_unit, misc);

            dec = stringGetterz("Enter 1 to continue: ");
        } while(dec.equals("1"));
    }

    public static String stringGetterz(String ny){
        System.out.println(ny);
        return rew.nextLine();
    }


  public static char charGetter(String cg){
        String sc;
        char cc;
        System.out.print(cg);
        sc=rew.nextLine();
        cc=sc.charAt(0);
        return cc;

    }




   public static void switches(int scholar, int u, double fpu, double mi){
        double discnt=0;
        switch(scholar){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Scholarship: Full Scholar..");
                    discnt=1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Scholarship: Half Scholar..");
                   discnt=.50;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Scholarship: Dean's Lister..");
                   discnt=.15;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Scholarship: None..");
                   discnt=0;
                    break;
        }

        double gf;
        double disc;
        disc =(u * fpu) *discnt;
        gf=(u * fpu) + mi - disc;
       System.out.println(gf);


    }

    public static void switchcase(char gender, int corz){
        double discnt=0;
        switch(gender){
                case 'M':
                case 'm':
                    System.out.println("Sex: Male");
                    break;
                case 'F':
                case 'f':
                    System.out.println("Sex: Female");
                    break;
            }




            switch(corz){
                case 1:
                     System.out.println("Course: BSIT...");

                    break;
                case 2:
                     System.out.println("Course: BSCS..");
                     break;
                case 3:
                     System.out.println("Course: BSCOE..");
                     break;


            }




    }



    public static void display(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\n" + "Year and Section: " + yearandsec);
        System.out.println("Units enrolled: " + units + "\n" + "Fee per unit: " + fee_per_unit + "\n" + "Miscellaneous: " + misc);
        switchcase(sex_code, ccode);







    }

    public static double doubleGetter(String dg){
        double fm;
        System.out.println(dg);
        fm=rew.nextDouble();
        return fm;


    }
    public static int intGetter(String scu){
        int iget;
        System.out.println(scu);
        iget=rew.nextInt();
        return iget;

    }

    public static String stringGetter(String ny){
       String sget;
        System.out.println(ny);
       sget=rew.nextLine();
       return sget;

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will work, but try initialising `rew` inside the main method.

Comment: Also, try replacing `dec.equals("1")` with `Integer.parseInt(dec) == 1`.

Comment: can you reindent the code please?

Comment: Fixed my answer, found your problem, don't know why it doesn't work as it is though.  Or why it works as much as it does in it's current form, either... :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Static fields are initialized the first time you initialize an instance of the class, so until you make a `new program()`, those fields won't exist.  Also, those fields are not going to exist in the main function.  rename your current main method to something like `run` and then use the following as a main method:</sup>

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    program p = new program();
    p.run();
}
```

EDIT: Apparently I'm wrong, the code can run.  Obviously, since you ran it...

Your problem is fixed by changing `rew.nextLine()` to `rew.next()` in `stringGetterz`.  Don't know why.

Comment: thanks its ok now.I'll just see what's the real problem behind that if I'm feeling lucky enough:}